# having trouble posting images on my website with php

Tags: php, image

I am able to list the images that  I have saved on an uploads folder on my server but I am not sure what I am doing wrong when it comes to posting the images up. I can list the names of the files but I cannot get the images to show up.

code:

```
<?php

        if ($handle = opendir('/home/kevin/html/uploads')) {
            echo "Directory handle: $handle\n";
            echo "Entries:"."<br>";

            while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
                //echo "$entry"."<br>";
                echo "<img src = "$entry" alt = " ">"."<br>"
            }

            closedir($handle);
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: missing `.` concatenation operator

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the quotes:

```
echo "<img src = \"$entry\" alt = \"\"><br>";
```

Comment: easier yo just use singles inside `echo "<img src ='$entry' alt=''><br>";`

Answer (score 0):

2 options:
1. Concatenate `echo "<img src = '".$entry."' alt = ' '>"."<br />"`
2. Escaping `echo "<img src = \"$entry\" alt =\" \">"."<br />"`